# Can mutiple quartz schedulers in a single application cause single log4j fileAppender stop rolling over?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, quartz-scheduler

Current application is on `Spring 3.2/JDK7/Quartz/Log4J2`, I have following `quartz` jobs scheduled below

Spring Quartz tiggers

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="trigger1" />
            <ref bean="trigger2" />
            <ref bean="trigger3" />
            <ref bean="trigger4" />
            <ref bean="trigger5" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Job interval definition

```
<bean id="trigger1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduledService1" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="5000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="2900" />
</bean>
<bean id="trigger2" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduledService2" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="7000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="3000" />
</bean>
<bean id="trigger3" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduledService3" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="9000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="3100" />
</bean>
<bean id="trigger4" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduledService4" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="11000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="3200" />
</bean>
<bean id="trigger5" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduledService5" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="13000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="2500" />
</bean>
```

I am trying to make them triggered in different time slot. In each `scheduledService` it referred to a service class with log4j logger instance. There is only one logger defined in log4j2.xml in the fileAppender, so all **logging information from the application writing into the safe file**.

My question is in such situation is it highly possible that if each logger write into the same logging file generated by `Log4J2` then it may cause `FileAppender` stopped rolling (because of muti threads I/O in the same Log file, then the log file grows crazily with huge file size)? If so how to overcome this issue? Must create different log file for different service class? I wonder if Log4j2 somehow can make above scenario wor